# Laravel select field validation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am currently building a feature where a user can select an option from a select box, once an item is selected you can click a button which hits my endpoint which submits and stores it.

However if i dont select anything but then click the button it just hits a 404 page on the same endpoint.

**Blade**

Below contains the blade syntax for the select box and button.

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md">
        <small class="text-success">
            please select one of the teams below to store your preference.
        </small>
        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['team.create.link', $team->id],'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'needs-validation','novalidate', null]) !!}
        {!! Form::select('teams[]', $teams, '', ['class' => 'custom-select', 'multiple'], ['required']) !!}
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-3 float-right">
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus-circle mr-2"></i>
            Add</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Method**

Below is the method used for storing the new input within the pivot table.

```
public function link(string $teamId)
{
    $team= Team::findOrFail($teamId);

    $links = Input::get('teams');

    $link = Team::findOrFail($links);

    $team->links()->attach($link);

    session()->flash('success', 'Link Added.');

    return back();
}
```

**Help**

How would i modify this so that the button cant be clicked and returns a required error if an option isnt selected? i've tried adding ['required'] to the form::select but i had no luck with that.

Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Comment: Add [`validation`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation) to your controller method. Don't rely on client side validation with `required`.

Comment: i've seen with Form::bsText you can just add 'required' can you not do the same thing for this use case?

Comment: HTML validation alone should prevent your form from being submitted. Try adding `type="submit"` to your `<button>` or change it into an `<input type="submit">`. What's the resulting HTML for the `<select>` tag?

Comment: @Lowtiercoder The HTML `required` will provide some validation, but you can just remove it in the inspector and your `required` validation is bypassed. Plus what is to stop people sending rubbish to your endpoint if you're not validating on the server?

Comment: @Unflux good point, i've added validation following the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate your Reqeust with `$this->validate`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function link(Request $reqeust, string $teamId)
{
    $request->validate([
        'teams' => 'required',
    ]);

    $team = Team::findOrFail($teamId);

    $links = Input::get('teams');

    $link = Team::findOrFail($links);

    $team->links()->attach($link);

    session()->flash('success', 'Link Added.');

    return back();
}
```

Take a look at the official Laravel Documentation for [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)